# How to add show "online" to enum Presence.Mode Smack 4.2.0

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have a problem with Parse stanza presence.
I get Presence with custom mode "online" from server but with Smack library 
Presence.Mode enum "online" is not contanst. How to add "online" or custom presence without change "online" presence mode from server.

Presence from server

```
<presence type='available' xml:lang='' to='3713c2a0-4269-11e6-b79f-9dbdb0ae436f_475a400a-292b-440c-981a-57af0b3f9a2c@antbuddy.com/9474679351501558172409360' from='3713c2a0-4269-11e6-b79f-9dbdb0ae436f_475a400a-292b-440c-981a-57af0b3f9a2c@antbuddy.com/9474679351501558172409360'><show>online</show><status>undefined</status></presence>
```

Error when parse presence

```
UnparseableStanza java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: online is not a constant in org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence$Mode
```

I'm using Smack 4.2.0

Comment: Never use custom stanza types. Instead annotate the stanza with a custom extension element.